# Recyclerview Loadmore Not Working After Search

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Past Few days,Facing this problem .**[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)** onscroll to Loadmore and EditText Search works fine.But When i search data and Get Respective Result List and Then if I Scroll **RecyclerView** then Loadmore not working .

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private  LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private  EditText editsearch;
    private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

    private int ival = 1;
    private int loadLimit = 10;

    ArrayList<Student> mDataSet = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Student> my_Dataset = getDataSet();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(my_Dataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search);

        // add the listener for EditText
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                mAdapter.filter(text);
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(
                mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {

                loadMoreData();

            }

        });

    }

    private ArrayList<Student> getDataSet()
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)
        {
            Student std=new Student();
            std.setName("Root" + i);
            mDataSet.add(std);
        }
        return mDataSet;
    }

    private void loadMoreData() {

       loadLimit = ival +5;

        for (int i = ival; i <= loadLimit; i++) {
            Student st = new Student("Student " + i,false);
            mDataSet.add(st);
            ival++;
        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
 public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Student> mDataset;
    private ArrayList<Student> mCleanCopyDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Student> dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
        mCleanCopyDataset = mDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        mDataset = new ArrayList<Student>();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            mDataset.addAll(mCleanCopyDataset);
        } else {
            for (Student item : mCleanCopyDataset) {
               /* if (item.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    mDataset.add(item);
                }*/
                if(item.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    mDataset.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here is **[EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e)**

I am new in Android-studio .Does any guys meet this issue?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're losing your reference where you want to add your items. Your current steps are:

1. Create list in mainactivity `ArrayList<Student> mDataSet = new ArrayList();`
2. Create adapter in mainactivty and pass my_Dataset (my_Dataset is mDataSet)
   `mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(my_Dataset);`
3. Init adapter (you save the reference of mDataSet here)
   `mDataset = dataset; mCleanCopyDataset = mDataset;`
4. Filter `mDataset = new ArrayList<Student>();` here you lose your reference

**Solution**

Rename `mDataset` to `mFilteredDataSet` inside your adapter and change your constructor like that:

```
public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Student> dataset) {
  mFilteredDataset = new ArrayList<>(); // init your filtered dataset just one time and clear it on filtering
  mFilteredDataset.addAll(dataset); // here you have your copy of the dataset
  mCleanCopyDataset = dataset; // this is your reference of the complete dataset
}
```

Change `mDataset = new ArrayList<Student>();` in your filter function
to
`mFilteredDataset.clear()`

Don't forget to call `mAdapter.filter()` at the end of your `loadMoreData()` because you add more data to your adapter but the new added data is not included in your filtered list.

Comment: Your answer may be perfect .Could you send me code.I am newbie

Comment: Just follow my solution instructions. It includes all the code you have to add/change. If you don't understand something of the solution feel free to ask.

Comment: I am newbie . could you send demo example .

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are a newbie. I posted the code you have to insert in your classes. I won't do your homework and post a complete code for copy & paste. I want that you understand the changes, not just copy & paste... Just follow my solution step by step. If my solution doesn't work for you, post the error / problem you get.